# Write a C# program to append additional text to an existing file with contents

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I did the following question given below with code and I got the following error described below

question: Write a C# program to append additional text to an existing file with contents. You are given a file named  "sentences.txt" with a few lines already stored in it.
Create a program to ask the user for several sentences (until they just press Enter) and append them in  "sentences.txt". Enter the below contents:
"C# supports abstraction and encapsulation.
C# supports inheritance and polymorphism."
The new content must be appended to its end. 
Display the entire contents of the text file on the screen.

my code :

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program      //DO NOT change the class name
{
    //implement code here
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter file = File.AppendText("sentences.txt");
            string line;
            Console.Write("Enter a sentence: ");

            do
            {   
                line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line != "")
                    file.WriteLine(line);
            }
            while (line != "");
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

this code is not able to read the file elements and not taking the input from the user also . How should I rectify it.

Comment: every IDE that I know of will format this with indents etc to make it more readable; please retain them - it is *actively painful* to look at the code as presented. I'm going to reformat it in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are writing the same line *very very fast* many many times to the file, and eventually a cog falls out, probably somewhere around the 2GiB mark. Try moving the `line = Console.ReadLine();` to **inside** the loop.

Comment: It is still not able to display the entire contents of the text file. How it can be done? @Marc Gravell

Comment: @parna you haven't shown a single line of code relating to anything that tries to display a text file, so I can't possibly guess

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program      //DO NOT change the class name
{
    //implement code here
    public static void Main()
    {   
        // Creating a file 
        string myfile = @"sentences.txt"; 

        // Appending the given texts 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Sentence");
        using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(myfile)) 
        { 
            sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
            sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
        } 

        // Opening the file for reading 
        using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(myfile)) 
        { 
            string s = ""; 
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) { 
                Console.WriteLine(s); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```